# Hangouts Chat Service Account issues

Tags: google-workspace, service-accounts, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am working on setting up a few new bots for Hangouts Chat.  Part of the effort involves using Hubot, which is working well.  Another use case requires posting to user spaces based on external functions, which is done via a python command script.  I have a project and separate service account setup for each bot, and the permissions for the bot service account appear to be the same.  None of the bots have corresponding domain-wide delegation at the GSuite Security level.

We obtain the spaceid for each user via one Hubot that saves their spaceid to a database, and the python script can then lookup the user and obtain that id.

However, only one of the 5 projects appears to be able to post a message to a user space.  All others get a 403 error and fail to post.  The same python script is used for any of the 'bots' with the only difference being the json file used for authentication.

Not sure this is enough information.  But, I wonder what could be causing this problem if not permissions?

Comment: Are you using the service-account on its own behalf or impersonating a user? Depending on the kind of requests you want to carry out [impersonation might not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011909/google-chat-api-g-suite-request-contains-an-invalid-argument-node-js/63242152#63242152).

Comment: Using the service account, which in the project where this does work appears as a message from the bot.  My issue is that it does not work on other projects, only one.

Comment: So is each of your service accounts linked to the respective project for which you are trying to use it (each service account is associated with a certain project) and is the Hangouts API enabled for each respective project?

Comment: Yes, each one works just fine with the same credential files, but via PubSub with Hubot.  All but one fail via python.  Yes, each service account is only used within its project.  This is because afaik you can only have one bot per project, so i just went ahead and set them all up with their own project.

Comment: Does any of the 5 projects work on its own, or only one specific one (if so - please try to find the difference between this one and the others).

Comment: They all work independently via Hubot.  I have tried comparing one that does not work with the one that does for PubSub, Hangouts Chat API, credentials, OAuth, etc.  Since we are on GSuite, they were also published as private into the marketplace so that we could approve them in the GSuite Admin.  So far I am not seeing any differences.  If I find it I will let you know here.

Comment: I figured it out.  The spaceid I was registering via another bot is not the same as the spaceid associated with the bot/user communication for any other bot.  In other words, it appears that the spaceid a bot sees for a user is unique to its communication with the user.  I will need to have users register with the bot that needs to send the message instead of a common registration bot.

Comment: Makes sense! I am glad you found the issue. Consider posting it as an answer in case other people encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The spaceid I was registering via another bot is not the same as the spaceid associated with the bot/user communication for any other bot. In other words, it appears that the spaceid a bot sees for a user is unique to its communication with the user. I will need to have users register with the bot that needs to send the message instead of a common registration bot